# Python function confusion

Tags: python

While programming with python I am often confused with the following ambiguity:

should it be: function(a) or a.function(). Although the question is too general and can someone tell me which situation happens when?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call it like a.function() you are calling a method named "function" from the object named "a".

If you don't know the difference between a method and a function/procedure, you need to study [Object Oriented Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) concepts.

Answer (score 4):

Your confusion potentially stems from how python defines instance methods...

```
class Person

    def speak(self, message):
        print message
```

Looking at that definition I can see how someone would think you have to pass a `Person` as the first argument.

but it is just python's way to make `self`, the current instance of the person, available to the method.

so the proper way would be

```
person_instance = Person()
person_instance.speak("This is a message")
```